# Как удалить git со всей историей в Intelij Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github

Проблема моя в том, что я неправильно залила проект. Возможно ли удалить все настройки гита в интелиж айдиа и историю чтобы заново нормально залить? Если да то как удалить?

Comment: удалить папку .git в проекте

Comment: не совсем понятно, что вы хотите удалить

Comment: я пыталась добавить проект на гитхаб, начиталась в интернете, и в терминале ввела команды чтобы добавить, в VSC добавляла репозиторий, но что-то пошло неправильно. Могу я удалить все что я сделала и   с нуля залить проект?

Comment: @Rolles подскажите пожалуйста где найти эту папку

Comment: @Енот немного не понял, удалить репозиторий? Или удалить в проекте VSC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама intellij не хранит историю, настройки гита и тем более связь с внешним репозиторием (типа на github). Intellij все это берет из репозитория git, который находится в вашем проекте.

Репозиторий либо создается командой `git init`, и тогда он будет в папке `.git` из которой запускалась команда `git init`. Либо репозиторий создается командой `git clone  git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`, и тогда он опять же хранится в подпапке `.git` папки `YOUR-REPOSITORY`.

Связь между вашим локальным репозиторием и удаленным создается либо в момент клонирования, либо (это наверно ваш случай) командами `git remote add ...`.

То есть есть несколько вещей, которые можно сделать:

1. удалить репозиторий (но не исходный код). Для этого удалите папку `.git` в проекте. Из IntelliJ не уверен, что это можно. Лучше из какого-нибудь файлового менеджера или терминала.
2. удалить remote репозиторий в github. Для этого пользуйтесь веб интерфейсом github.com

После этого вы сможете заново сделать `git init` в корне проекта и заново залить локальный репозиторий на github.