# Не грузит файлы на Git из Intelij IDEA, загружает только файл gitignore

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, github

Изначально загрузил неверный файл gitignore. Потом полностью удалил репозиторий с github, попробовал перезалить исправленный, но почему-то отображается старая версия, в которой исключается вся папка с проектом. Загружает только файл gitignore, причем загружает все равно неисправленную версию. Я новичок в этом, подскажите как исправить?
Файл gitignore загружает только в таком виде, исправления не отображаются:

```html
#############
## Idea
#############
target/
.idea/
.idea
.repository/
*.iml
*.iws
*.jrtc
*.java
*.class
*.info
*.properties
*.jar

/1.JavaSyntax/
/2.JavaCore/
/3.JavaMultithreading/
/4.JavaCollections/
/5.OnlineInternship/
/out/
/JavaRushPlugin.properties
/Instruction.png
/out.log
/out.log.*
```

Comment: Доп. информация помогла решить проблему:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251687/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-git-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-intelij-idea?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

удалить файл или папку с гита

```
git rm -r --cached fileName
```

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Заново загружаю все, а gitignore старая версия остается, даже дата старая(

Comment: значит что то не так делаете. Переходите на уровень папок где лежит файл и набираете команду с правильным именем файла?

Comment: Удаляю весь репозиторий на сайте GitHub, а может быть другой результат если удалить с помощью командной строки?

Comment: может стоит попробовать?

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться как это сделать, впервые с git работаю:)